# Tensorflow: multi-scale training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, yolo

I am trying to train a multi-scale CNN some kind like YOLOv2 in Tensorflow:
to randomly resize the batch of inputs every several epochs.
But I am not so familiar with Tensorflow, the following is how I get batches of images and labels:

```
data_provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset)
image, label = data_provider.get(['image', 'label'])
inputs, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], \
                                    batch_size=128, \
                                    num_threads=4,  \
                                    capacity= 1000, \
                                    min_after_dequeue=616)
```

Then I hope I can resize the batch of inputs and feed into network

```
rand_size=int(np.random.uniform(0.15,1)*720)
resize_output = tf.image.resize_bilinear(preprocessed_inputs, [rand_size,rand_size],align_corners=True)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work, it only resize the batch at the beginning, and apply the resize operation to all the inputs

Anyone have suggestions for what I should do? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You want `rand_size` to be based on a `tf.random_uniform` rather than numpy/int, otherwise it will have the same value for each run of your `session`.

```
rand_size = tf.random_uniform(
    minval=int(0.15*720), maxval=720, dtype=tf.int32, shape=())
```

This will still resize each element of the batch by the same amount.

I'm not familiar with how `slim` does preprocessing, but there'd be something in there that allows you to do the above before batching (in which case you'd get a different random value each time). Alternatively look into using the more recently released [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828616/streaming-large-training-and-test-files-into-tensorflows-dnnclassifier/45829855#45829855) might help you there.