# How can I implement a random shear preprocessing layer in tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am looking for a layer that randomly shears a batch of images, such as the preprocessing layers in `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing`. However, there doesn't seem to be any such layer.

There are a few similar questions to implementing shear layers in TF, but those use deprecated methods in `tf.contrib` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938836/shearing-image-in-tensorflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214953/tensorflow-is-there-a-way-to-implement-tensor-wise-image-shear-rotation-transl)). Can someone point me in a direction to implement random shears in tensorflow 2?

Comment: if I understood your question correctly, check out `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`

Comment: That isn't quite what I'm looking for, I want to shear an image after I have already loaded it, I'm looking for a layer that shears

Answer (score 1):

Few of the operations of tf.contrib in Tensorflow 2.x is moved to Tensorflow addons.
Equivalent for `tf.contrib.image.transoform` is `tfa.image.transform`
For more details on library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/transform)

And also take a look at Random_shear using [tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/random_shear)